# Cdktf data source for any resources

Tags: terraform, cdktf

I want to get id of any resources using resource name is there any way?

Example If I wanted to get id of storage account or virtual machine or anything else how can I achieve using single block instead declaring calling data source of particular resources

Comment: Could you explain to what id you are referring? Do you mean the one inside the cdktf program or the one that the cloud provider of your choice assigns to the resource?

Also what do you mean by using single block?

Comment: ID here means the one which generate for resources in cloud, which is refference to resource id

Comment: What do you mean by single block?